# StreamWriter save file as ANSI

Tags: vb.net

I have a function in my application which creates a text file:

```
Dim fajl As System.IO.StreamWriter
fajl = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:/file.txt", True) 
fajl.WriteLine("107,1,______,_,__;2;" & pgr & ";" & plu & ";" & pretvoriTocke(row("mpc")) & ";" & naziv & ";")
fajl.close()
```

The problem is, when my application creates a file that file is saved as UTF 8 but i need it to be saved as ANSI.

Comment: `Using sw = New StreamWriter("c:\file.txt", False, Encoding.ASCII)`

Comment: Use Encoding.Default

Comment: ANSI doesn't mean anything. When you read *ANSI* somewhere, the Local encoding is *probably* what is meant (related to the `[CultureInfo].TextInfo.ANSICodePage`, MS *naming convention*). So `Encoding.Default` will encode using the System's current `CodePage`. If you need a specific encoding, you can use: `Dim culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hr-HR") Dim encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(culture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage)`, for example.